# Django: Django not recognizing post variable

Tags: python, django

I'm probubly missing something very basic, but when I try to accsess a post varaible by means of: `request['title']` in a function, I get this error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/ajax/drafts/create

Django Version: 1.4
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'Knights',
 'django.contrib.admin')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  20.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/Mike/Desktop/Main/Django-Development/BBN/Knights/views.py" in document_create
  179.     title = request.POST['title']
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/utils/datastructures.py" in __getitem__
  258.             raise MultiValueDictKeyError("Key %r not found in %r" % (key, self))

Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError at /ajax/drafts/create
Exception Value: "Key 'title' not found in <QueryDict: {}>"
```

The full code for the function is this:

```
def document_create(request):
    user = request.user
    title = request.POST['title']
    if (title != ''):
        Draft.objects.create(content='Your content goes here', user=user, title=title)
```

and the post variables listed are this:

```
POST:
title = u'sdff'
```

Edit: Also, when I list through the items with a for loop, the title variable comes up.

Comment: `Request Method: GET` ... **`Request Method: GET`**

Comment: You are trying to access the POST dict in a GET request. The error is caused because you are doing a GET request to the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The request that caused the error was a GET, and you are trying to get the value of the `title` parameter from the POST dict.
Change your code to:

```
def document_create(request):
    user = request.user
    title = request.GET['title']
    if (title != ''):
        Draft.objects.create(content='Your content goes here', user=user, title=title)
```

Or, you could test if the request is a GET or a POST, checking the `request.method` attribute.

Comment: Also if you don't care whether it's in POST or GET you could do: `data = getattr(request, request.method)`

Comment: @D.A: Or you could just use `request.REQUEST`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that your request is really a POST? For me it look like your are trying to retrieve data from a POST request but the query is in reality a GET request.

Also, you should use `if 'title' in request.POST:` to check the presence of the variable in request...

Regards

Etienne

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, this is a GET query, so the POST dict will be empty. Did you mean to set `method='POST'` in your form element in the HTML?

Secondly, `KeyError` means the key wasn't in the `POST` dictionary. You should be doing:

```
title = request.POST.get('title', None)
if title is None:
    ...
```

This sets `title` to `None` if the key is not in `request.POST`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean "when I list through the items with a for loop, the title variable comes up." It would be useful to add what you actually got, because what you are saying shouldn't be possible.